# mapply and SIMPLIFY and not stripping classes

Tags: r

I am having an issue using lapply and mapply returning data.  Namely that mapply / lapply returns a list of lists.  And if I "simplify" the call it strips out the class information.

For example:

```
library(lubridate)

addBusDays <- function(d, dd) {
 d 
}

# start with datframe
dates <- c(ymd('2013-03-04'), ymd('2013-03-07'))
my.df <- data.frame(n=c(1,2), d=dates)

mapply(addBusDays, my.df$d, 1, SIMPLIFY=F)
```

returns

```
[[1]]
[1] "2013-03-03 19:00:00 EST"

[[2]]
[1] "2013-03-06 19:00:00 EST"

class(mapply(addBusDays, my.df$d, 1, SIMPLIFY=F)[[1]]
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

It looks like it is returning a list of lists, which is workable but I don't lke the solution.  Allowing the function to simplify strips the POSIX class:

```
mapply(addBusDays, my.df$d, 1, SIMPLIFY=T)
class(mapply(addBusDays, my.df$d, 1, SIMPLIFY=T))

> mapply(addBusDays, my.df$d, 1, SIMPLIFY=T)
[1] 1362355200 1362614400
> class(mapply(addBusDays, my.df$d, 1, SIMPLIFY=T))
[1] "numeric"
```

this looks to return a single list, but strips out the class info.  ANy help / ideas?

Working orking off of Gavin's suggestions

```
library(lubridate)

addBusDays <- function(d, dd) {
  d 
}

# start with datframe
dates <- c(ymd('2013-03-04'), ymd('2013-03-07'))
my.df <- data.frame(n=c(1,2), d=dates)
my.df$d.2 <- as.POSIXct(mapply(addBusDays, my.df$d, 2, SIMPLIFY=T), origin="1970-01-01")

typeof(my.df$d)
class(my.df$d)
mode(my.df$d)
typeof(my.df$d.2)
class(my.df$d.2)
mode(my.df$d.2)

my.df
```

returns

```
> my.df
  n                   d        d.2
1 1 2013-03-03 19:00:00 2013-03-04
2 2 2013-03-06 19:00:00 2013-03-07
```

The technique is shifting the day by 1 - it shouldn't in this example as the function returns the date passed in...  Other than that the class etc seems spot on.

And I my eyes are fooling me - my problem is in loading the data frame - not with Gavin's solution.

Comment: `mapply` is returning a list, each component of which is a vector of class `"POSIXct"`, inheriting also from class `"POSIXt"`.

Comment: still not sure how to apply the function and return a list of class POSIXct - are you able to nudge me in that direction?

Comment: Your wish is my command - see my Answer, now updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is the `do.call()` idiom:

```
> do.call("c", mapply(addBusDays, my.df$d, 1, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
[1] "2013-03-03 18:00:00 CST" "2013-03-06 18:00:00 CST"
```

Wherein we get R to arrange to call the `c()` function with input data given by the list returned from `mapply()`.

An alternative, which is most likely going to be quicker for large data that the `do.call` idiom is:

```
> as.POSIXlt(mapply(addBusDays, my.df$d, 1), origin = "1970-01-01 00:00.00")
[1] "2013-03-03 18:00:00 CST" "2013-03-06 18:00:00 CST"
```

or more wrapped back to a `"POSIXct"` object

```
> as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(mapply(addBusDays, my.df$d, 1),
+                       origin = "1970-01-01 00:00.00"))
[1] "2013-03-03 18:00:00 CST" "2013-03-06 18:00:00 CST"
```

Comment: I was considering the second option thinking it was kludgy.  But this may be the direction I go, if I cannot get a 'prettier' answer

Comment: The second option is no kludge - you must set an origin for R to understand what the numeric number of seconds from refers to.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt, accurate, and courteous response.